# How to use quotation marks inside a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, formatting, punctuation

I have a short story which I've split up so each line of the story is a new element in a JavaScript array.

However, some lines of the story use quotation marks as punctuation so they can't be used as array entries as they break the code, for example:

> And she began: "Thou makest thyself so dull
>   Ne'er ran as thou, who thitherward returnest."
>   And said: "Already did I rest content
>
> ```
> var shortstory = ["And she began: "Thou makest thyself so dull", 
> "Ne'er ran as thou, who thitherward returnest."", 
> "And said: "Already did I rest content"]
> ```

Is there a way to format the text strings so that they can be used inside an array? I've tried replacing the quotation marks with unicode characters (U+201C & U+201D) but this doesn't work.

Comment: show your split code

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with arrays, it's about string literals. String literals are written within quotation marks (either `"` or `'` can be used, but they have to match). So `"abc"` is a string literal that defines a string with the letters a, b, and c in it. If you want to have a `"` within a string quoted with `"`, you have to *escape* it with a backslash: `"And she began: \"Thou makest..."`. See the linked question's answers for more. I also suggest working through some basic JavaScript tutorials or a good JS book. (Also note you can't have unescaped newlines.) Happy coding!

Comment: *"I've tried replacing the quotation marks with unicode characters (U+201C & U+201D) but this doesn't work."* It should do. It [works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/pjb36gk0/1/). Note that I had to remove an unescaped newline.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation and for pointing me towards the other answer!